# flex-How to load video from local disk and play

Tags: apache-flex

I am developing a flex 4 application. The VideoPlayer component plays video when I place it in /web-root/video/myfile.flv. But my application will have alot of videos and hence I am supposed to store them in a separate directory, say, D:\mysitedata\videos. So I tried playing the video from this location but I get a playbackError.

`<s:VideoPlayer width="800" height="600" complete="vpCompleteHandler(event);" loop="false"                 mediaPlayerStateChange="vpMediaPlayerStateChangeHandler(event);"
                   source="D:\mysitedata\videos\myfile.flv" />`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to sue local and network resources at the same time. The Flash player does not like this by default. There is a great article on how to get around this at the following URL:

http://www.indieas.org/2009/09/error-2148-or-how-to-access-local-and-network-resources/

I am summing that you are running a kiosk like application since you are accessing local resources. Remote users will not be able to access your D: drive.

If you would like remote users to access your drive than you should create a virtual folder that points to your videos folder, and then use that virtual folder in the source path of the video.